# want to add nice date format and want to check it in database too .suggest me a nice dd/mm/yyyy date format

Tags: php, date

I am using dob as password.it should be given by user in dd/mm/yyyy format.and i want to compare it with database to see it is correct or not.

Comment: no it is not correct way .

Answer (score 0):

this in not correct way.please use **MD5 hash** to secure your password

use `md5($str)`

Comment: i just want to select date and store it in database using dd/mm/yyyy format

Comment: use before save md5('dd/mm/yyyy') or before check md5('dd/mm/yyyy')